# Login using weChat in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, wechat

I want to login using WeChat in my app like facebook,google and twitter and i download the sdk and sample code from WeChat site but there nothing about login using wechat.
     Please suggest me how to login using WeChat in my app.

Comment: have you got solution for login with wechat ?

Comment: @Theorist, hello yes i got the solution and i implement in my app.

Comment: i Create Account here :  https://open.weixin.qq.com/ , Set up my application i got APPID and APP_SECRET. using that not able to login with we chat. i found that for login API i pay 300 yuan  to wechat. after pay i will able to login ?

Comment: Hi Nikunj
can you tell me what you have done for the wechat login?

Comment: How to do login: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069029/how-do-i-do-authorization-and-login-with-wechat-using-the-ios-sdk/38069132#38069132