# WeChat Login Autorization is not happenning in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wechat

I am trying to Login my App with We\chat in iOS(swift).
1. I have added all the following: 
[I have followed all the steps specified in this link][1]
[1]: [How do I do authorization and login with WeChat using the iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069029/how-do-i-do-authorization-and-login-with-wechat-using-the-ios-sdk) 2. In the AppDelegate.swift, I have added the code as:`if authResp.code != nil {
      let dict = ["response": authResp.code]
      nc.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "WeChatAuthCodeResp"), object: nil, userInfo: dict)
}`
3. After this step: Wechat app asked for authorization, I allowed it, after that some link is loaded in mobile browser: but this is not loading, empty page is showing 4. I haven't got any response code in the function, provide me solution for this or any guidance to get the Authorization code 5. As soon as Login Button is clicked, It is communicating with We chat App, and a link is opening in a browser to get the authorization code. The link could not able to complete it in the browser. Kindly help me on getting the Authorization code