# How to get the auth code from we chat SDK

Tags: swift, wechat-auth

I try to do we chat social login integration, I follow the we chat documentation steps, I logged in to we chat I got appid and secrete id from credential but I didn't get the auth code I got error like this for the API:

Request:
https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/oauth2/access_token?appid= appid&secret= secret&code=CODE

Please suggest me where I can get this auth code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do authorization and login with WeChat using the iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069029/how-do-i-do-authorization-and-login-with-wechat-using-the-ios-sdk)

Comment: After I login in also I didn't get code, Because  onResp(_ resp: BaseResp) function is not calling after sendAuthReq is hit, But it redirect to login, This is what my exact problem is